How many $5$ or $6$-letter words can be created with $1$ a, $2$ b's, and $3$ c's?
How many $5$ or $6$-letter words can be created with $1$ a, $2$ b's, and $3$ c's?
I have calculated the number of permutations of all $6$ letters (all $6$-letter words) using $$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!} = \frac{6!}{1!2!3!} = 60$$
I am having trouble figuring out how to find all the $5$-letter permutations now.

Welcome on MSE! It is not clear (at least for me) what you are asking for. You are considering 6-letters words with one A, two B's and three C's. And now you are talking about 5-letters words. What condition do we have on those new words?

If we are talking about 5 letter words with at most one A, at most two B's and at most three C's, I guess you could distinguish three cases: the first one where the A is missing, the second one with only one B, and the last one with two C's.

@Kolakoski54 I just figured it out using those three cases then calculated the total number of permutations for each case (using the equation I used above) and added them up. Thanks!

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Since you figured out how to solve the problem, please consider answering your own question.

There is a bijection between the six-letter permutations and the five-letter permutations.

Do these have to be valid english words? Or just combinations of letters

When you have $1$ time a, $2$ times b and $3$ times c, then the construction of five-letter "words" is done using:

$1$ a, $2$ b's and $2$ c's => number: $\frac{5!}{1! 2! 2!} = 30$
$1$ a, $1$ b and $3$ c's   => number: $\frac{5!}{1! 1! 3!} = 20$
$2$ b's and $3$ c's        => number: $\frac{5!}{2! 3!} = 10$

=> all together you can create $60$ "words" using five of the six mentioned letters. 

We have the generating function as:
$ f(x)=\left ( 1+x \right )\left ( 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} \right )\left ( 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} \right )\\
\Rightarrow 5!\left [ x^5 \right ]f(x)=60$
